How to delegate modifications privileges on NICs only?
I would like to delegate the ability to configure NICs to a specific domain group without giving full admin privileges. How would one proceed to do that?
On Linux I can allow such delegation by allowing writes to systemd-networkd files to a specified group, or create polkit rules for that group. What is the Windows equivalent?

Add the account to the local Network Configuration Operators builtin group.
